# building TensorFlow: bazel cannot find libstdc++ in non-standard directory

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

I am trying to build MKL-accelerated version of TensorFlow using bazel 0.5.1, gcc 6.2, binutils 2.28, Anaconda2 python on Scientific Linux 7.2.
Apparently the system /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 is too old, so I am trying to use gcc installed in another directory. PATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH are modified to prepend the corresponding paths (using modules). However, while bazel has no trouble picking up correctly executables for gcc, ld, python, it still tries to load old system /lib64/libstdc++.so.6. How to force it to use the one from gcc 6.2? Why does not it pick it up from LD_LIBRARY_PATH?
According to google many people are having trouble with this but I could not find a solution that would work for me. I had no trouble building TensorFlow under Ubuntu 16.04 that has sufficiently new gcc in the standard location.

I do:

1) ./configure
The only non-default options I choose is use MKL and download MKL

2) bazel build --config=mkl --copt="-DEIGEN_USE_VML" -s -c opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package

.....

example/example_parser_configuration.proto tensorflow/core/protobuf/control_flow.proto tensorflow/core/protobuf/meta_graph.proto tensorflow/core/protobuf/named_tensor.proto tensorflow/core/protobuf/saved_model.proto tensorflow/core/protobuf/tensorflow_server.proto tensorflow/core/util/event.proto tensorflow/core/util/test_log.proto)
ERROR: /scratch/midway2/ivy2/TF_intel/tensorflow/tensorflow/tools/tfprof/BUILD:42:1: null failed: protoc failed: error executing command bazel-out/host/bin/external/protobuf/protoc '--python_out=bazel-out/local-opt/genfiles/' -I. -I. -Iexternal/protobuf/python -Ibazel-out/local-opt/genfiles/external/protobuf/python ... (remaining 5 argument(s) skipped): com.google.devtools.build.lib.shell.BadExitStatusException: Process exited with status 1.
bazel-out/host/bin/external/protobuf/protoc: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by bazel-out/host/bin/external/protobuf/protoc)
bazel-out/host/bin/external/protobuf/protoc: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version`CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by bazel-out/host/bin/external/protobuf/protoc)
bazel-out/host/bin/external/protobuf/protoc: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by bazel-out/host/bin/external/protobuf/protoc)

.....

Thank you,
Igor

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the slow reply. Bazel by design ignores LD_LIBRARY_PATH when running actions. It doesn't have to ignore them during C++ toolchain detection, but at the moment, it does :/ To help you forward, I would try adding --sysroot= as linkopt or using bazel grte_top flag. Depending on where your libstdc++.so lives, you might need to disable sandbox. The principled solution would be to write a custom CROSSTOOL that specifies builtin_sysroot or grte_top. But that is not an easy task.

Let me know if I lost you somewhere in that paragraph :)